# I can't input a file to my code using code blocks

Tags: input, codeblocks, fstream

Sorry, I'm new to programming. I've tried checking other related questions on here and either the examples don't make sense to me or the buttons they say to click won't let me click them. I'm trying to do my final homework for CIS22A, and right now I'm stuck at opening the file my teacher wants me to open. She teaches us in microsoft vs, but I use codeblocks cause they never sent me a code to download vs for free. This is my code, it shows no errors but it won't read the file I want it to read, and the file is in the same folder as all my cpps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("universities.txt");

    //Check for errors
    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "File does not exist." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the complete pathname of the folder containing your source files?